# How to get values from another Table according to values in one column in SQL

Tags: sql, conditional-statements

from the below query,

```
SELECT  [BusinessDate],[Identifier],[Rate]
  FROM [JAM].[dbo].[FXHistory]
  WHERE BusinessDate = '2021-11-26'
```

I have this output

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[![FXHistory][1]][1]
```

from this query,

```
SELECT 
       [ProductID],[ProductIDType],[CloseDate],[Last]
FROM [JAM].[dbo].[PricingHistory]
where [ProductID] IN ( 'PAJAU ID Equity' , 'PAJAE ID Equity' , 'PAJKU ID Equity' , 'PAJKE ID Equity' , 'PAJMU ID Equity')
AND [CloseDate] BETWEEN '2021-11-26' AND '2021-11-26'
ORDER BY CloseDate;
```

I have this output

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[![PricingHistory][1]][1]
```

when the forth character of the ProductID is "E" I want to add the "EURJPY" rate and when end with "U" add the "USDJPY" rate. Something like

```
ProductID        Shares  Last  Rate
PAJAE ID Equity   132425  265   128
PAJAU ID Equity   53364   126   113
```

how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The below will get you the rate corresponding to EURJPY for E and USDJPY for U. For anything else the rate will not match and will show up as null.

```
  select x.ProductID
           ,x.Shares
           ,x.Last
           ,y.rate
       from FXHistory x
   left join (select case when identifier='EURJPY' then 'E' 
                         when identifier='USDJPY' then 'U'
                     end as col1
                    ,rate 
               from PricingHistory 
              where Identifier in ('EURJPY','USDJPY')
             )y
         on SUBSTRING(ProductID,4,1)=y.col1
```

Comment: Thank you. Still can't get what I need. but am playing with your code to have something.

Comment: what do you need

Comment: I changed the fifth line from FXHistory to  PricingHistory , and viseversa in line 10, also  change the identifier to Identifier. but got a lot of errors. sorry don't know which error is important to paste here.